# How to get list of member login names within a group using SP workflow action

Tags: 2013, workflow, workflow-activity

I am creating a custom workflow activity in SharePoint 2013 Workflow. I need to get the set of user logins in a SharePoint site group so that I can send a mail to all users in the group.

In the workflow action list there is a action as "SPLookupGroupMembers". But it asks for a "GroupPrincipalId". The action "LookupPrincipalId" asks for a user name not a group name. How can I get the group ?

Answer (score 0):

[image]

this what you need to send mail to members within a group

Comment: I have already tried in SharePoint Designer. I want to know how to do it in Visual Studio Custom Activity